# How to incorporate unittest in cmake project structure

Tags: cmake

I'm working on an embedded project. As a part of this project, I have unit-tests that use gcc and Gtest. The question what is the best to approach to incorporate these unit-tests. My current implementation is that I have a different build type called unittest. I have a clause of CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE and decide which sources to use which targets to create. I see this is not a good design and this screws up multiconfiguration gnerators. What could be the elegant solution for this?

Thanks in advance for answering.

Comment: Normally a project has some option, using which one could enable or disable building tests.

Answer (score 2):

Create separate executables for testing and use ctest:

`add_test` to add the combination of executable+command line parameters as a test `ctest` runs and `enable_testing()` in the toplevel `CMakeLists.txt`.

This allows you to simply run ctest in the build dir and you can pass a configuration to test using `-C` command line option.

```
add_executable(MyTest test.cpp test_helper.cpp test_helper.h)
target_include_directories(MyTest PRIVATE .)

target_link_libraries(MyTest PRIVATE theLibToTest)

add_test(NAME NameOfTest COMMAND MyTest --gtest_repeat=1000)

enable_testing()
```

Running ctest from the build directory runs a test named NameOfTest. For multi configuration generators you simply specify the configuration to test with the `-C` command line option

```
ctest -C Release
```

Of course you can use `add_test` multiple times to add different test executables or the same test executable with different command line options.

Furthermore I recommend figuring out a way of storing results in a file, since this makes via the test parameters, since ctest's output probably won't do the trick. I'm not familiar enough with gtest to give advice on this.

Btw: `ctest` treats exit code 0 as success and any other exit code as failure, but I guess gtest produces executables that satisfy this property.

If you don't necessarily want to build the tests at the same time as the rest, you could exclude them from all, possibly adding a custom target that depends on all of the unit tests and is also excluded from all to allow building all of them at once.

You could also use a cache variable to toggle testing on and off:

```
# enabled via -D TEST_MY_PROJECT:BOOL=1 parameter for cmake
set(TEST_MY_PROJECT 0 CACHE BOOL "enable tests for my project")

if (TEST_MY_PROJECT)
    # testing setup goes here
endif()
```